# Chrome fails to load HTTPS page

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, https

I am using Chrome 5.0 on Ubuntu 10.04, and this is the error I am getting:

[image]

Other HTTPS sites work fine on Chrome, including those with self-signed certificates. I even tried using Incognito mode, no dice.

The same site works fine on Firefox.

Does anyone have any idea on why this is happening? Or how I can get a more useful error message?

Comment: I'm afraid without specifically naming the site you're trying to visit, we can't be of much help here... Any specific reason why you erased the address from the screen shot?

Comment: @Blood It's an internal website, you can't access outside of our intranet anyways.

Comment: @NullUserException Even that may be a clue as to why this happened for the experts on this amongst us.

Comment: I also happen to be admin of the server I am trying to access. Error logs don't show anything.

Comment: @Blood Server is running on Apache with mod_ssl. Key and certificates were generated and signed using openssl. I can access the server itself, but I am forcing all connections to use https - and it actually redirects me to the right place. It just fails to load and displays that message

Comment: @NullUserException: Are your proxy settings the same with Firefox and Chrome? Can you confirm that another https site works in Chrome using the same proxy (or absence of a proxy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved after looking into Opera's much more descriptive errors:

#### "Unable to complete secure transaction" and "Secure connection: fatal error (554)"

This led me to Opera's support page and it's explained that this is caused by the certificate not being good enough. I re-did the keys and certificates and everything works fine now on both Chrome and Opera.

Comment: What does "re-did the keys and certificates" mean? There's one specific site (https://maven.apache.org) I can't get to.

Answer (score 0):

Looks a lot like this http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=37549 which was merged with http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30891 and fixed 3/2010.